# Attempting to sum the distance of an array of LatLng

Tags: android

I'm trying to sum up the total distance between an array of LatLng but failing hard. Here's what I've got so far:

```
private double sumDistance() {
    Location loc = new Location("distance provider");
    double previousLatitude;
    double previousLongitude;
    float[] results = new float[1];
    for (LatLng latLng : mMapList) {
        previousLatitude = latLng.latitude;
        previousLongitude = latLng.longitude;
        loc.distanceBetween(previousLatitude, previousLongitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, results);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this is that the latlng for both are the same. Is there some way I can get the previous latlng or a cleaner way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double previousLatitude;
double previousLongitude;
float[] results;
for (int i=0; i<mMapList.size(); ++i) {
    LatLng latLng = mMapList.get(i);
    if (i == 0) {
        // Previous weren't set yet, nothing to measure
        // Set them and skip loop
        previousLatitude = latLng.latitude;
        previousLongitude = latLng.longitude;
        continue;
    }

    // Measure previous with current
    loc.distanceBetween(previousLatitude, previousLongitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, results);
    // ~ Use the distance

    // Modify the previous ones
    previousLatitude = latLng.latitude;
    previousLongitude = latLng.longitude;
}
```

Comment: `-1 -1` is still a valid coordinate. Use `Double` instead of the primitive value and check if it's not null.

Comment: @PedroOliveira or check if it's the first iteration as I've done in my updated answer.

Comment: Took me a second to get my head round this piece of code, this is perfect, great code.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you assign the "previous variable" after you've calculated the distance? Something like this should work

```
private double sumDistance() {
    Location loc = new Location("distance provider");
    double previousLatitude = mMapList.get(0).latitude;
    double previousLongitude = mMapList.get(0).longitude;
    float[] results;
    for (int i=1;i<mMapList.size();i++) {
        loc.distanceBetween(previousLatitude, previousLongitude, mMapList.get(i).latitude, mMapList.get(i).longitude, results);
        previousLatitude = mMapList[i].latitude;
        previousLongitude = mMapList[i].longitude;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also great code, both do exactly what they're supposed to. :)